# Weird input button issue IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, input

Im having an awkward issue with internet explorer at the moment. Any page that i have that includes an  the button appears extremely small and with a line instead of the text entered in value=. I have tried removing the style sheets from the pages but the issue persists. If anyone could shed some light on this for me it would be appreciated.

```
<input style="height:50px; width:150px; text-indent:hanging;"  type='submit' name='submit' value="Submit"/>
```

Now this is just one example but any submit button i create will be extremely small with just a --- in it instead of font. In the example i set the height and width and the button will be that size but the text inside is still just ---- though on firefox and crhome it they all sa whats in the value field. And as suggested in the comment below im not on windows xp or using a custom theme.

Comment: gotta share some code my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSS rule that sets the font size to something very small, in some part of the document that is not included in the code snippet you posted. You will probably see this if you test with a document that contains nothing but the tag you posted.

Comment: as i stated in the op i had tried removing the link to the css file i use to format everything and there was still the issue. Ill comb threw one of them again and see if i can find something though. maybe in the table?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me when I put it in a blank document so you must have css somewhere else that is taking over.  Trying using developer tools or firebug to see what all CSS is being applied to the button.  You may find its inheriting from somewhere else.  If not some more code in context of how it's being used may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can define your button css in External [File check to this click here](http://jsfiddle.net/BH95f/2/)
http://jsfiddle.net/BH95f/2/
Now this is run every browser with ie